# What does wide-rolling mean?

Tags: grammar, meaning

This excerpt come from A Romance of the South Seas by Herman Melville

> Six months at sea! Yes, reader, as I live, six months out of sight of
>   land; cruising after the sperm-whale beneath the scorching sun of the
>   Line, and tossed on the billows of the **wide-rolling** Pacific.

Does wide-rolling mean the wide and undulating Pacific?

What's the purpose of combining the two words: wide and rolling?

Comment: Yes, the wide, undulating Pacific. What book is this? It rolls [the waves] over the wide Pacific. It's just poetic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My interpretation:

It is referring to very low frequency ocean waves.

That construct is used to make 'wide' and adverb for 'rolling' and not an adjective for Pacific.